# Have php sprintf omit return if string is empty

Tags: php, mysql

I am wresting with printing shipping labels and getting the final output to omit a second address line if one exists. Is there a way to conditionally exclude the line break if $address2 is empty when using sprintf()?

```
            while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $name = $rows['address_name'];
                $address = $rows['street1'];
                $address2 = $rows['street2'];
                $citystatezip = $rows['city'].', '.$rows['state'].' '.$rows['zip'];
                $country = $rows['country'];
                $text = sprintf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", $name, $address, $address2, $citystatezip, $country);
                $pdf->Add_Label($text);
            }
```

Comment: What prevents you from checking if `$adress2` is empty before using `sprintf` and using an alternative pattern if required?

Comment: why not two sprintfs? `if (address is empty) { sprintf(without address); } else { sprintf(WITH address); }`? and note that sprintf is pointless in this case. all you're doing is concatenating some strings. you're using any formatting options, so sprintf is a megaton nuke being used to swat a fly in one room of one building in the city. just use a fly swatter, which you're ALREADY doing with the `citystatezip` stuff earlier.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Very helpful. Got it on the update needed to PDO. @Marc B: Will ditch sprintf and use printf.

Comment: don't even need printf. none of what you're doing requires it. `$text = "{$name}/{$address}/{$address2}/{$city},{$state},etc...."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sprintf only has 4 '%s' and 5 params.

In this code, I removed the \n from the sprintf into a conditional above.

```
        // Don't use mysql_xxxx functions
        // Should really be using PDO       
        //          +---------------+
        //          |               |
        while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $name = $rows['address_name'];
            $address = $rows['street1'];
            $address2 = $rows['street2'];
            $citystatezip = $rows['city'].', '.$rows['state'].' '.$rows['zip'];
            $country = $rows['country'];
            $addr2 = empty($address2) ? '' : $address2 . "\n";
            $text = sprintf("%s\n%s\n%s%s\n%s\n", $name, $address, $addr2, $citystatezip, $country);
            $pdf->Add_Label($text);
        }
```

Comment: This works great. Will combine this with the input given above to update the mysql part etc. Thanks ryantxr